# How to assign plain XML to C# variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use XML Literals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768762/use-xml-literals-in-c)

I can do this in Visual  Basic, How can I do this in C#

```
    Dim xmlTree As XElement = <Employees></Employees>
```

Comment: C# (at least 4 and below) does *not* support XML literals. `new XElement("Employees")` would work here, but XElement can also parse larger [verbatim] text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768762/use-xml-literals-in-c , http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84852/TRICK-Xml-Literals-for-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse("<Employees></Employees>")
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse("<Employees></Employees>")
```

or

```
XElement root = new XElement("Employees")
```

Another way is using `XmlDocument` class:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<Employees></Employees>");
```

but I recommend to use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). It is newer than `XmlDocument`,  it has more clean API and support [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).